# Methods for first order PDEs in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What are the possible known methods for solving first order PDEs in higher dimensions? Is there anything else besides the method of characteristic curves?

In particular, I have four first order, linear, non-homogeneous PDEs in 8 dimensions which I (unfortunately) have to solve analytically.

Comment: Characteristic curves are the way to go, in general.